# Setting a threshold value for QProgressBar

Tags: c++, qt

I'm showing instantaneous values from a sensor with a `QProgressBar`.

The sensor value can range from `0 to 0.5`

In order  to show these values on `QProgressBar`, I transformed the range (`0-0.5`) in an integer range by multiplying by 100

[0 , 0.5] -> [0 , 50]

```
 ui->progressBar->setRange(0, 0.5*100);

 ui->progressBar->setValue(sensor_value*100.0);
```

so that when receiving a new value, I multiply it by 100  ( 0.12*100 = 12/50)

Now I've a `QDoubleSpinBox` to select a "threshold" value for `QProgressBar`, shown below:

[image]

I did the following in order to transform `QDoubleSpinBox` value into the threshold and use this threshold to generate a sound when the `QProgressBar` reaches the threshold

```
threshold = ((ui->doubleSpinBox->value()*100)/50); //---> not sure if this is right

ui->label->setText(QString::number(threshold, 'f',2 ));

if(sensor_value > threshold)
       {
           ui->rdo_btn_vertical->show();
           ui->rdo_btn_vertical->setStyleSheet(StyleSheetOn1);
           QSound::play(":/resources/beep1.wav");
       }
```

However, the problem here is I'm not getting the correct threshold in the above calculation. So that I cant compare the threshold value and actual sensor value is displayed on the QProgressBar
Can anybody spot some issues there?

Comment: I don't understand. Is `sensor_value` the exact value taken from the sensor (so, in a 0-0.5 range)? If that's so, you don't need any conversion from the progress bar, since it's taken from the spinbox.

Comment: Be careful with integer vs double operations: could you try with `ui->doubleSpinBox->value()*100.0/50.0` ? Any good compiler should complain about this, yours did not?

Comment: `so that when receiving a new value, I multiply it by 100 ( 0.12*100 = 12/50)`: What do you mean? 0.12*100 = 12, not 12/50?

Comment: Supposing that the `doubleSpinBox` has a value in the range of [0,50], why are you using `*100/50`? Do you want to show 0.12 or 12?

Answer (score 0):

widget.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class Widget; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    double threshold;
    ~Widget();

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
};
#endif // WIDGET_H
```

widget.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"
#include<QLabel>
#include<QTimer>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->progressBar->setRange(0, 0.5*100);
    ui->senser->setRange(0,0.5);
    ui->senser->setSingleStep(0.01);

    //setting threshold value from threshold spin box
    connect(ui->thresholdSpinBox,QOverload<double>::of(&QDoubleSpinBox::valueChanged),[&](){
         threshold = ((ui->thresholdSpinBox->value()*100)/50);
    });


    // i am taking senser value from another double spin box manually
    connect(ui->senser,QOverload<double>::of(&QDoubleSpinBox::valueChanged),this,[&]()
    {
            ui->progressBar->setValue(ui->senser->value()*100);
            if(ui->senser->value() > threshold)
               ui->notifier_label->setText("alert greator than threshold");
            QTimer::singleShot(3000,[=](){ui->notifier_label->clear();});

    });
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

set up ui like this and run this code , maybe you will get your answer
[image]